# Uploading file with php

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, file-upload

I have the following set up in a Code Igniter application, however the file is not being passed through to the file uploader class. This is the second form on the page, just for reference and I have checked that they are both closed correctly.

The output I am getting is `You did not select a file to upload.` when I have been selecting an valid image.

**View**

```
<form action="../albums/upload" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="userfile" required="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <input type="submit" id="upload" name="upload" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function upload() {
    if($this->input->post('userfile')){
        $this->model_photo->do_upload();
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function do_upload() {
    $path = base_url().'res/image/';
    $config = array(
        'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png|tif|tiff',
        'upload_path' => $path
    );

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        echo $error['error']; //echo debugging purposes
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        echo $data['upload_data']; //echo debugging purposes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `<form>` add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form action="../albums/upload" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: You're kidding... I looked at this and thought I had it in there but didn't actually check. I feel like an idiot now. Thank you!

Comment: I was once an victim of this too and wasted 2 hours noticing it .

Comment: Was just coming to accept today. I finished up last night before the 15 min went past.